# Synonyme für "(über)schwappen"

Tags: synonym

Ich suche nach guten Synonymen für das Verb "schwappen". Es geht um das Verhalten einer Flüssigkeit, die ihr Gefäß, z.B. bei einem Stoß, verlässt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hier einige Synonyme und verwandte Begriffe (sie drücken allerdings nicht implizit die  Ruckhaftigkeit von *"überschwappen"* aus):

- überlaufen
- übergehen
- übertreten
- überquellen
- überfließen
- überborden
- überströmen

Comment: +1 for *überborden*, the other ones seem more a synonym of *überlaufen*, esp. when the **amount of water is increasing.**

Comment: "*überwallen*" would be another expression (used for larger amounts of liquid).

Answer (score 2):

There are many words we don't use in everyday speech e.g.: überwallen . If you want to write a poem then you can use words from 1782 :-D like Schiller in [Fantasie an Laura](http://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Fantasie_an_Laura)

If you are looking for synonyms you can try: [Synonym Woxicon](http://synonyme.woxikon.de/).

From my POV there is no so comon expression like: überschwappen, überschwabbern (Ruhrpott-Slang). I think überlaufen would also be right :D

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe noch den Vorschlag "schwabbern".
My suggestion is "schwabbern".

"in kleinen Wellen überfließen" : 
"to overflow in little surges"

Comment: *"schwabbern"* may be regionally used for *"schwappen"*, but it has more the meaning of *"schwabbeln"*.